# eventlistener() won't update html element after single form submission

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to take 4 values that a user inputs into a form while also doing some basic error handling of checking to see if an input element is empty. My blank paragraph right at the start of my `<body>` with `id="demo"` is my means of checking all of this.

When pressing submit with an empty input element, my program does catch this and updates my my paragraph to notify the user to fill in all fields. But from there, the paragraph doesn't update `innerhtml` of thing when the submit is valid. The submit doesn't work regardless as the empty paragraph never updates to the value of colmax.

I've added `onsubmit="return false"` to my form to prevent it from resetting the page but I'm so lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

```js
// why does this need to go before variable declarations to work
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", newFunction);

const errormsg = document.getElementById("errormsg").value;
const colmin = document.getElementById("colmin").value;
const colmax = document.getElementById("colmax").value;
const rowmin = document.getElementById("rowmin").value;
const rowmax = document.getElementById("rowmax").value;


function newFunction() {
  //blank element we will be changing
  var thing = document.getElementById("demo");

  // Check if all fields are entered
  if (colmax == "" || colmin == "" || rowmin == "" || rowmax == "") {
    //if so then change thing to this.
    thing.innerHTML = "Please enter every field";
    return false; // why do i need to return false for this to work?
  }
  // if all field are entered change thing to this.
  thing.innerHTML = "maximum col value is: " + colmax;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="msg">
  <p id=errormsg></p>
</div>


<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>
<p>This tries to uses the addEventListener() method to read data from a form with error handling and updating
  <br> however, values won't update after changing them and pressing submit again. as seen when chaging max column value entry.
  <br> between different numbers and between no input to input.
</p>

<table id='mytable'></table>

<section class="container">

  <!-- onsubmit stops page from resetting -->
  <form id="myform" onsubmit="return false">
    <div>
      <label for="colmin">Minimum column value (between -50 and 50):</label>
      <input type="number" id="colmin" name="colmin" min="-50" max="50">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="colmax">Maximum Column Value (between -50 and 50):</label>
      <input type="number" id="colmax" name="colmax" min="-50" max="50">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="colmax">Minimum Row Value (between -50 and 50):</label>
      <input type="number" id="colmax" name="colmax" min="-50" max="50">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="colmax">Maximum Row Value (between -50 and 50):</label>
      <input type="number" id="colmax" name="colmax" min="-50" max="50">
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- <button id="btn">Submit</button> -->
      <input id="btn" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of , you can skip those null checks by just add required to the input tag

i wasn't with my laptop earlier
but i tinker with you code and fixed some problem

first thing is you cant set an id more that once , you used colmax multiple times

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Multiplication table</title>
    <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">      -->
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="msg"><p id=errormsg></p></div>


<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>
<p>This tries to uses the addEventListener() method to read data from a form with error handling and updating
    <br> however, values won't update after changing them and pressing submit again. as seen when chaging max column
    value entry.
    <br> between different numbers and between no input to input.
</p>

<table id='mytable'></table>

<section class="container">

    <!-- onsubmit stops page from resetting -->
    <form id="myform">
        <div>
            <label for="colmin">Minimum column value (between -50 and 50):</label>
            <input type="number" id="colmin" name="colmin" min="-50" max="50" required>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="colmax">Maximum Column Value (between -50 and 50):</label>
            <input type="number" id="colmax" name="colmax" min="-50" max="50" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="rowmin">Minimum Row Value (between -50 and 50):</label>
            <input type="number" id="rowmin" name="rowmin" min="-50" max="50" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="rowmax">Maximum Row Value (between -50 and 50):</label>
            <input type="number" id="rowmax" name="rowmax" min="-50" max="50" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- <button id="btn">Submit</button> -->
            <input id="btn" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">

        </div>
    </form>

    <script>

        // why does this need to go before variable declarations to work
        document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', e => newFunction(e))

        const errormsg = document.getElementById("errormsg").value;
        const colmin = document.getElementById("colmin");
        const colmax = document.getElementById("colmax");
        const rowmin = document.getElementById("rowmin");
        const rowmax = document.getElementById("rowmax");


        function newFunction(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            //blank element we will be changing
            let thing = document.getElementById("demo");


            // if all field are entered change thing to this.
            thing.textContent = "maximum col value is: " + colmax.value;
        }
    </script>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use innerhtml expect you really need to which may be never , use textContent rather

Comment: While your code remedies part of the problem, it doesn't seem to update upon a resubmission with another number

Comment: copy the entire code it's working fine, i just checked